# How to ignore style changes in styled-components during snapshot tests in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, styled-components, snapshot-testing

Assume i have a simple component I wish to snapshot test:

```
const Component = styled.div`{
  color: red;
}`
```

My snapshot test wishes to ensure that the div renders, but the styling is not important. So if I did a snapshot test on this `Component`, and i changed `color` from red to blue, and a new classname is generated, it would not fail the snapshot test.

In short, is there any way I can either ignore className in snapshot tests, or tell styled-components to generate static class names to be deterministic in tests?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the [`jest-styled-components`](https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components) package which does exactly this.

For an example like yours, this would result in a snapshot like this:

```
exports[`it works 1`] = `
.c0 {
  color: red;
}

<div
  className="c0"
/>
`;
```

where `c0` is always stable.